# What should we do with information about duplicate user?

Tags: discussion, users, duplicate-accounts

In chat I have seen a statement like

> I am "*****" with my friend account...stack overflow suspended me for vote my posts with another account...anyway

**** is a username.

Do we have to report it to Stack Exchange team? If yes, where can we do it?

I think it is not a duplicate, because I want to find out how should I handle such a situation. I'm not asking for a new feature to report users.

Comment: *"stack overflow suspended me for vote my posts with another account"* let me guess, they then bitched how they weren't doing that and the mods are being unfair? all the while using *another* account

Comment: I think it is not a douplicate

Comment: @Jens A flag is something simple an universal and with a custom reason it is easy to use. Also if you think it is not a duplicate edit your question and explain init *why* you think it isn't a duplicate.